Chrome randomly opens a popup when opened from VBA for Excel

How can I disable Chrome (ver.125) pop-up help/hint like the one in attached image?
It shows up at random time and stays visible for a few seconds, but it screws up my script.
I can't find proper option in Chrome (ver.125) settings to disable it.
Here's what will/should reproduce the situation :
'Excel 2010; VBA 7.0
Dim oChrm As ChromeDriver
Set oChrm = New ChromeDriver
If oChrm Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
With oChrm
  .Start "CHROME"
  .Window.SetPosition 0, 0
  .Window.SetSize 1920, 1080
  .Get "https://stackoverflow.com"
End With 'oChrm
'no matter what the script does here,
'at some point in time (after 5-15 secs)
'browser pops-up a help/hint (for 5-10 secs)
'like the one attached to OP (or similar)
'and that is a show stopper:
'VBA error could be anything from
'NoSuchElement, StaleElement to
'UnknownError, UnknownProblem, etc.

This problem shows up in the latest Chrome version only, ver.125. I guess it's a new feature and there's gotta be a way to disable it.

try this: oChrm.AddArgument "--disable-notifications", before you do your Get.

@igittr: thanks for a hint; no changes. Also, I saw here in Java this option is added before new ChromeDriver is created.  I guess in VBA it is done differently.

here is another suggestion: --suppress-message-center-popups.  Yes, add options before you start chrome.

thanks. how do i add options before the line Set oChrm = New ChromeDriver ?

add it as the first statement within your "with oChrm", before the .Start.

@igittr: thanks for your hint; no changes. Anything else to try?
